# Can MACD be calculated for values other than 12 and 26?

Tags: time-series, finance, python, technical-analysis, moving-average

I am working on time-series classification problem using Convolutional Neural Networks in Python. The data-set used is financial stock market data (like yahoo finance). I am using some technical indicators calculated using raw values high, low, volume, open, close.

One of the technical indicators is MACD (Moving Average Convergence Divergence) using [TA Library](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/technical-analysis-library-in-python/latest/technical-analysis-library-in-python.pdf). However, it is written, in most places, that it is calculated for `n_fast = 12` and `n_slow = 26` periods (considering trading period to be 6 days which is 5 days in our case) with RSI (Relative Strength Index) being calculated for 14 days and `n_sign = 9` (parameter of `macd_diff()` in TA library).

So, if I am calculating RSI for 5 days analysis period (with 5 days trading period) then how do we set these `n_fast` and `n_slow` values according to it? Should these be `n_fast = 3` and `n_slow = 8`. Also, what should be the value of `n_sign` then?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the [TA-lib documentation](https://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/func_groups/momentum_indicators.html) on momentum indicators.

While the example for MACD contains 12 and 26:

```
macd, macdsignal, macdhist = MACD(close, fastperiod=12, slowperiod=26, signalperiod=9)
```

you are free to set them to other numbers.

There are also examples for MACD that use a `context` at this [source code browser](https://programtalk.com/python-examples/talib.MACD/). One function uses

```
talib.MACD(prices,context.SHORTPERIOD,context.LONGPERIOD,context.SMOOTHPERIOD)
```

and you will have set `context` from the caller.